# Adding a new font to FOP. couldn't find main class. program will now exit

Tags: java, classpath, xsl-fo

I am trying to add a new Font to FOP.

I start creating a metric font file by running this:

java org.apache.fop.fonts.apps.TTFReader C:\WINNT\Fonts\msgothic.ttf
msgothic.xml

But I keep getting the same error: Could not find the main class: org.apache.fop.fonts.apps.TTFReader . program will exit.

I guess I should add fop.apps.TTFReader to my java path, but I can't figure out how.

Thanks in advance for your help,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you get points at not finding the main class. [Here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/fop/fonts/apps/TTFReader.java.html) you can see that there is no main method in this class. That results in not being able to call its functionality in the way you tried.

If you're using FOP 1.0, there are ways to autodetect fonts from a directory or from the systems font folder, or even from a jar you build containing fonts. Check [this tutorial](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.0/fonts.html).

Cheers,
Wim